# Is it true that the subdifferential is empty if and only if $f$ is infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am interested in conditions when the subdifferential is empty.

> Claim:
>
> If $f$ is lower semicontinuous, convex, proper, then $\partial f(x) = \emptyset$ if and only if $f(x) = +\infty$

Is this true?

I know that $f(x) = +\infty \implies \partial f(x) = \emptyset$.

But is the reverse true?

$\partial f(x) = \emptyset \implies f(x) = +\infty$?

If not, is there a general condition that says when $\partial f(x)$ is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-\sqrt{x} &\quad \text{if } x \geq 0, \\
\infty & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is closed and convex, and $\partial f(0) = \emptyset$ despite the fact that $f(0)$ is finite.

Comment: This is really strange. I thought that intuitively, a function only becomes non-subdifferentiable if the function goes to $\infty$ at some point at the boundary. Maybe I am stuck thinking of the x^2 over open domain and $+\infty$ else where.  But now looking at the graph of -sqrt(x), it seems that the condition is the slope of the line becomes vertical.